# How to make image scale beyond list item width?

Tags: html, css, image

The following does not scale the image beyond the list item width.
If the list item width is also scaled so that the image will scale, a large gap is placed between the list item number and text.

How can this be done without weird behavior?

HTML:

```
<ol>
 <li>Item 1<br>
 <img class=scale src="image001.gif" alt="" />
 </li>
</ol>
```

CSS:

```
img.scale {
    width: 90%;
}
```